# I am getting an routing error message from an application I am creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I included `get '/favorites', to: 'favorites#index'` in my `config/routes.rb` and I am getting an error and im not really sure what the issue is

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant FavoritesController):

bootsnap (1.4.4) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant'
bootsnap (1.4.4) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
bootsnap (1.4.4) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
bootsnap (1.4.4) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `inject'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `constantize'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:88:in `controller_class_for'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:81:in `controller_class'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:46:in `controller'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
```

this is half of the error message, I chose not to post the whole entire thing because it may be too long for stack overflow

Comment: please add code from favorites controller and link/form you click.

Comment: Can you show your favorites controller?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't created the `FavoritesController` class. Create `app/controllers/favorites_controller.rb` and define the controller with an index action. Assuming you have a Favorite model class you can do this:

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @favorites = Favorite.all #uses Favorite model
  end
end
```

After that you could get an error from the view if you don't have a view set up for the index action in `/app/views/favorites/index.html.erb` you could just create that file and it will have access to `@favorites` from the controller.

You could generate all of this running this generator in your console:

```
rails generate controller Favorites index
```

And changing the generated route.

Comment: I actually do have the class

Comment: can you provide your file favorites_controller.rb location and the controllers def @hannah

Comment: try getting the FavoritesController to load in the rails console. Just run `rails console` and inside do `FavoritesController` if you get an `uninitialized constant FavoritesController` error then go back and make sure the spelling is right in file name and the class definition. The file must be `app/controllers/favorites_controller.rb` so that the class inside is autoloaded

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a controller, does the error go away if you add the following to your routes file?  Would it be possible for you to run "rake routes" and post the output?

```
resources: favorites
```